# How to count conditionally with iteration with python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, networkx

How can I change the dataframe below to the form like df2?

I have a bunch of raw data for networkx analysis in python

The dataframe is now processed to be like df:
each id is one user id
A B C D E are binary data representing whether the product is bought on that date ( 1: bought)

```
df
date        id     A       B      C    D    E  
20170601    1001   1       1      0    0    0
            1002   0       1      0    0    1
            1003   0       1      1    1    1
            1004   0       1      0    0    1
20170602    1001   1       0      1    0    1
            1002   1       0      1    0    1
            1003   0       1      0    0    1
            1004   0       1      0    0    1
```

I would like to process data into the following form

```
df2  
target1      target2       Weight
  A             B             1     (the time where A & B both = 1)
  A             C             2     (the time where A & C both = 1 )
  A             D             0
  A             E             2
  B             C             1
  B             D             1
  B             E             5
  C             D             1
  C             E             3
  D             E             1
```

I can create this data frame by counting myself but i have a lot of products over 50 and it will take a lot of time to count it manually by using only:

```
df[(df.A == 1) & (df.B == 1)].sum()
```

and itertolls might help

```
list_product = list(itertools.combinations(df.columns,2))
dataframe = []

for i, i+1 in range(list_product):
    count = df[(df[i] == 1) & (df[i+1] == 1)].sum()            
    dataframe.append(df.columns[i], df.columns[i+1], count)
```

Is these anyway to create this table in a faster way?
(might have some method with iteration...)

Your help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted attempt with itertools is pretty close:

```
list_product = list(itertools.combinations(d.columns,2))
counts = []

for a, b in list_product:
    count = ((d[a] == 1) & (d[b] == 1)).sum()            
    counts.append([a, b, count])

counts = pandas.DataFrame(counts, columns=["Target1", "Target2", "Count"])

>>> counts
  Target1 Target2  Count
0       A       B      1
1       A       C      2
2       A       D      0
3       A       E      2
4       B       C      1
5       B       D      1
6       B       E      5
7       C       D      1
8       C       E      3
9       D       E      1
```